# PHP mkdir failed to created directory in server

Tags: php, mkdir, permission-denied

I have problem in creating folder in server (centos), there is a form with file upload field, where the ajax callback always returned error as:

> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/sitename/public_html/inc/callback/request_update.php on line 90
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(../../images/listing/16/805202.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sitename/public_html/inc/callback/request_update.php on line 95
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpnrtrdp' to '../../images/listing/16/805202.jpg' in /home/sitename/public_html/inc/callback/request_update.php on line 95

and its indicate the line in file `request_update.php` is causing the error:

> mkdir($output_dir, 0755, true);

**request_update.php:**

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){

foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

    $file_name = $key.'_'.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

    //explode fine name and extension
    $ext_x = explode('.', $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
    $ext = strtolower(end($ext_x));
    $file_name = str_replace('.'.$ext, '', $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);

    //new file name
    $output_dir = '../../images/listing/'.$list_id;
    $new_file_name[] = rand(1, 999999).'.'.$ext;
    $pathfile = $output_dir.'/'.end($new_file_name);

    // create directory if does not exist
    if(is_dir($output_dir) == false){
        mkdir($output_dir, 0755, true); /*this is where error indicate*/
    }

    if(is_dir($pathfile) == false){

        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $pathfile)){
            
            //watermark
            $water_path = '../../images/watermark.jpg';
            $watermark = WideImage::load($water_path);
            
            //resize original image
            WideImage::load($pathfile)->resize(300, 360)->merge($watermark, '50% – 25', '100% – 40', 80)->saveToFile($pathfile);

            
        }

    }

}

}
```

I've been tried the same code run in another shared server and even localhost, the folder can be created fine all the time, what is happen?

Comment: make ur directory writable, `chmod a+w images/listing/listing/16/`

Comment: Have you tried with `mkdir($output_dir, 0777, true);` ? , Just for testing purpose..

Comment: @Shankar, been tried 0777 but failed also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add to *Simon Groenewolt* comment-answer, is that you should start from checking if *PHP* can really write in the path you want, by using [`is_writable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) function:

Example:

```
$filename = 'test.txt';
if (is_writable($filename))
  {
    echo 'The file is writable';
  } 
else
  {
    echo 'The file is not writable';
  }
```

Just set proper permission, as stated by *Log1c* on the directory you're trying to write in, by running  `chmod a+w /yourpath/yourdir`, which is `666`, meaning *read* and *write* for all, a `user`, an `owner` and the `world`.

---

> *is_writable()* Returns TRUE if the filename exists and is writable. The filename argument may be a directory name allowing you to check if a directory is writable.
>
> Keep in mind that PHP may be accessing the file as the user id that the web server runs as (often 'nobody'). Safe mode limitations are not taken into account.

#### EDIT 1:

Make sure that *PHP* `open_basedir` setting, is also set to access `/tmp`. You could just disable it for testing purposes, to see what you get. Try checking what is `open_basedir` settings are set to, by running:

```
echo ini_get('open_basedir');
```

Comment: yes, I just with embed this codes, it show `The file is not writable`, what shall I do in server setting?

Comment: @conmen What is the output of terminal command: `ls -lsa /path_to/images/listing/`?

Comment: output: `4 drwxr-xr-x 13 moment69 nobody 4096 Apr  4 19:41 ./
4 drwxr-xr-x  5 moment69 nobody 4096 Apr  2 00:44 ../
4 drwxr-xr-x  2 moment69 nobody 4096 Apr  4 00:18 1/
4 drwxr-xr-x  2 moment69 nobody 4096 Apr  4 00:18 10/
`

Comment: It seems that you're running Apache as nobody (mod_php) and you have for `group` *xr* value. Run `chmod 666 /path_to/images/listing` to make sure that `group` can also write and so far `group` (Apache running as nobody) can only *read/execute*, which is `(xr)`. I should solve your problem.

Comment: @conmen What is the output of `echo ini_get('open_basedir');` running from PHP?

Comment: I've deleted my answer, yours is more complete :-)